# How to covert multiple .txt files into .csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, file-io, concatenation

I'm trying to covert multiple text files into a single .csv file using Python. My current code is this:

```
import pandas
import glob

#Collects the files names of all .txt files in a given directory.
file_names = glob.glob("./*.txt")

#[Middle Step] Merges the text files into a single file titled 'output_file'.
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for i in file_names:
        with open(i) as in_file:
            for j in in_file:
                out_file.write(j)

#Reading the merged file and creating dataframe.
data = pandas.read_csv("output_file.txt", delimiter = '/')
  
#Store dataframe into csv file.
data.to_csv("convert_sample.csv", index = None)
```

So as you can see, I'm reading from all the files and merging them into a single .txt file. Then I convert it into a single .csv file. Is there a way to accomplish this without the middle step? Is it necessary to concatenate all my .txt files into a single .txt to convert it to .csv, or is there a way to directly convert multiple .txt files to a single .csv?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might want to label your "middle step" with a comment. I don't see a problem with your code, as it does everything you said you needed.

Comment: do you know the column names ahead of time?

Comment: Yes, the column names will be known ahead of time, and are the same for all of the text files. There will be between 3 and 5 text files at a time to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. And you really don't need to involve pandas here, just use the standard library `csv` module. If you know the column names ahead of time, the most painless way is to use `csv.DictWriter` and `csv.DictReader` objects:

```
import csv
import glob

column_names = ['a','b','c'] # or whatever


with open("convert_sample.csv", 'w', newline='') as target:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(target, fieldnames=column_names)
    writer.writeheader() # if you want a header
    for path in glob.glob("./*.txt"):
        with open(path, newline='') as source:
            reader = csv.DictReader(source, delimiter='/', fieldnames=column_names)
            writer.writerows(reader)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you for noting that the stdlib `csv` module is sufficient for this. It's disturbing how often folks are willing to add `pandas` as a dependency solely for basic csv processing.

Comment: @MichaelRuth yeah, it really drives me up the wall.

Comment: When i try this, I get a blank row in between rows with values. Would it be something to do with the `newline=''`?

Comment: @thentangler are you omitting that?

Comment: No I am not. When I open in excel I see alternate blank rows, but when I try printing in python I see hex Unicode nuls like ‘/x00’. How do I decode that?

Comment: @thentangler it sounds like encoding issue. You should try explicitly setting the encoding when opening the files for reading/writing. it's hard to say without more information, but maybe you are writing with utf16 encoding or something. as for the blank rows, you need to check if they are actually there before telling me what excel is showing you. What actually happens when you do something like `f = open(mfile, 'rb'); first_two = [next(f), next(f)]; print(first_two)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, That worked perfectly! it was `UTF-16-LE` and i had not specified it.
Thank You so much!!!